# get every nth byte/value in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking for a smooth/fast way to retrieve every nth short in a byte array and copy it to a new array.

l = lowerbyte
u = upperbyte

My data is of the following form:
 byte[] bytes= {a0l, a0u, b0l, b0u, c0l, ..., n0l, n0l, a1l, a1u, b1l, ..., nXl, nXu}

What I need is to get get n byte arrays of length X (e.g., a[0..X], b[0..X], ... or M[a..n][0..X])

I was thinking of the following two steps:

1. convert values to short (=> short[] shorts= { a0, b0, c0, ... n0, a1, .. nX})
   by using something like

   ```
       short[] shorts= new short[(int)(Math.Ceiling(bytes.Length / 2.0)];
       Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, shorts, 0, bytes.Length);
   ```
2. retrieve every second value from shorts

   ```
      I'm looking for some fast code here... something like blockcopy with skip
      I am completely aware that I could use a loop - but maybe there's a better
      solution to it as I need to do this task for 80MB/s...
   ```
3. convert it back to byte arrays (same same - using blockcopy)

   ```
       byte[] arrayX = new byte[shorts.Length * 2];
       Buffer.BlockCopy(shorts, 0, arrayX , 0, arrayX .Length);
   ```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might as just well copy the bytes directly to the new byte array, having calculated the correct offset for each short.

Converting it all to a separate short array and back to a byte array is a waste of time IMO.

Comment: You are completely right - and that is actually what I wish for - but then I'd need a fast way to copy packets of 2 every nth time. By converting to short I don't need that but can rather hope for a fast way to peek/get every nth value